# Wasn't able to display background picture url

Tags: html, css

[image]

I wasn't able to display the picture and I don't know what is
subdirectory to go down from css folder to images folder since I tried.

```
background: url('images/home1.jpg') top left no-repeat;
```

Comment: You shouldn' use "'" in url() and in this case valid path is ../images/home1.jpg, not /../images/home1.jpg.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `background` shorthand in the wrong order. The right order is:

> - background-color
> - background-image
> - background-repeat
> - background-attachment
> - background-position
>
> See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

The right syntax for `background` in your case would be:

`background: #fff url("../images/home1.jpg") no-repeat top left;`

Comment: It didn't work at all and the picture still didn't display.

Comment: I am sorry, I updated the code because it had a small error.

Comment: In the index.html it includes the content in the #slide element

Comment: @user3078858 I have updated the code in my answer, please use the new one. It works fine. If it doesn't, you have another problem.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by Amar Syla is correct, however, it doesn't really point out what the issue was to begin with. First of all, as he/she mentions, the shorthand syntax for the `background` property is **CORRECT**. However, if a particular property is not mentioned, the browser tends to use the default property. Which means, in this case, the absence of `background-color` property is a non-issue. See this in the snippet below (the `background-color` property isn't mentioned, however, the `background-image` renders just fine) :

```css
div {
    background: url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/desktop-year-of-the-tiger-images-wallpaper.jpg') top left no-repeat;
    height: 300px;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**The real problem with your code is the image path.** Based on the folder structure you have provided in the screenshot, the path must be :

```
background: url('../images/home1.jpg') top left no-repeat;    /*Correct path*/
```

instead of

```
background: url('/../images/home1.jpg') top left no-repeat;   /*Wrong path*/
```

Hope that helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just put ../ return directory path because your in currently in CSS folder.

background: url('../images/home1.jpg') top left no-repeat;